# Check that a hash includes another hash

Tags: ruby, hash, ruby-1.9

Given that I have an array of hashes `abc` and a hash `ghi`:

```
abc = [{
  'a' => '1',
  'b' => '2',
  'c' => '3',
  'd' => '4'
}]
ghi = {
  'a' => '1',
  'b' => '2'
}
```

what is the cleanest and most efficient way of selecting hashes from `abc` that contain all of the key-value pairs in `ghi`?

I was able to do this:

```
abc.map {|n| n.slice(*ghi.keys) == ghi }.all?
```

although it doesn't look very clean.

Comment: Do you mean an array of hash? and not array of hashes? because an array of hashes would mean something like [ {'a' => '1', 'b' =>  '2'}, {'a' => '77', 'c' => '24'} ]

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean, the example presented just happens to have only one element.

Comment: You can not use `def` as a variable name

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Ruby 2.3.

```
abc.select{|h| h >= ghi}
```

Note: This was answered before the OP mentioned the Ruby version.

Prior versions of Ruby:

```
abc.select{|h| h.merge(ghi) == h}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using Ruby 1.9, thank you. I updated my question to include my Ruby version.

Comment: Your prior version solution seems to produce an empty array

Comment: I was just going to say that you just misplaced h and ghi :) But let me just tell, that I admire how cool your Ruby answers are, really - short, precise and efficient (even though I do not know for sure, but you most likely do).

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is the fastest.

```
abc.select{|hash| (ghi.to_a - hash.to_a).empty?}
```

Comment: Good answer, but `ghi.to_a` should be moved out of the block. Yes, that adds a line and a variable, but sometimes you have to just grit your teeth and do it.

Answer (score 0):

For all keys and values check, you can try:

```
abc = [
  {
    'a' => '1',
    'b' => '2',
    'c' => '3',
    'd' => '4'
  },
  {
    'a' => '33',
    'b' => '23'
  }
]
d = {
  'a' => '1',
  'b' => '2'
}
abc.select{|hash| ((hash.values <=> d.values) == 1 ) && ((hash.keys <=> d.keys) == 1 )}
# => [{"a"=>"1", "b"=>"2", "c"=>"3", "d"=>"4"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
abc.select{|h| ghi.all?{|k,v| h.key?(k) && h.value?(v) } }
```

**Benchmark result:**

```
require 'benchmark'
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report { 10000.times { abc.select{|h| ghi.all?{|k,v| h.key?(k) && h.value?(v) } } } }
  x.report { 10000.times { abc.select{|h| h.merge(ghi) == h } } }
  x.report { 10000.times { abc.select{|hash| (ghi.to_a - hash.to_a).empty? } } }
  x.report { 10000.times { abc.select{|hash| (hash.values <=> ghi.values) == (hash.keys <=> ghi.keys) } } }
end

       user     system      total        real
   0.040000   0.000000   0.040000 (  0.037253)
   0.040000   0.000000   0.040000 (  0.046138)
   0.150000   0.000000   0.150000 (  0.155893)
   0.020000   0.000000   0.020000 (  0.028176)
```

Looks like Rajarshi's answer is the most efficient among all the answers.